# Can't get MonoTouch binding library to work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I can't even get the simplest kind of binding library to work - I must be doing something fundamentally wrong...

I created an Xcode project called “TestLib” that looks like this:

```
//  TestLib.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TestLib : NSObject
{
    NSString *status;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *status;
@end

//  TestLib.m
#import "TestLib.h"
@implementation TestLib
@synthesize status;
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setStatus:@"initialized"];
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

The project is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31924320/TestLib.tar.gz

I compiled this into “libTestLib.a”.

Then I created the simplest binding library I could (along with a “single view application” to test it), which simply initializes the TestLib class and calls the getter for the status property.  I added the library (libTestLib.a) into the binding library so it has the LinkWith file / assembly directive.  The ApiDefinition.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace TestLibBinder
{
      [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
      interface TestLib
      {
            [Export("status")]
            string Status { get; set; }
      }
}
```

That project is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31924320/BindingTest.tar.gz

Unfortunately I get a null reference back from the library when I try to get the Status property…

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
              base.ViewDidLoad ();

              TestLib testLib = new TestLib();  // succeeds!
              string status = testLib.Status;  // got a null reference

              if (status != null)
                    label.Text = status;
              else
                    label.Text = "binding failed";                  
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by stepping away from the Binding Library project approach and instead basing my code on the [BindingSample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BindingSample) in the xamarin sample suite.

Anyone who wants to build a C# binding to objective-C code using MonoTouch should really start by reviewing the Makefile in that project.  The approach it outlines is:

> 1. Explicitly compile the Objective-C code for the three architectures (ARM6, ARM7, i386)
> 2. Use lipo to create a single universal static library
> 3. Use btouch to create the DLL and include the static library through the assembly directive (LinkWith) - see AssemblyInfo.cs in that
>      project - as well as in the btouch commandline through the --link-with
>      option.

I personally found the process of creating the ApiDefinition.cs wrapper to be fairly straightforward, but there are some common mistakes - e.g. forgetting the trailing colon on a selector that takes one parameter.